# How to organize functions/methods in android app?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application, when user presses Sync button (calls function `onSynchronize()`), I need to do the following activities:

1. form url for data synchronization based on user's preferences
2. download url
3. parse data received
4. for each item found in data download picture (another url)
5. update `ListView` with data downloaded and parsed

What is the best approach to split this activity between classes? Since steps 2-4 should be done in background (`ASyncTask`), and the same steps 1-4 will be used in the service (for automatic synchronization).

Should I put step 5 in `onPostExecute` of according `ASyncTask`? Or, should I put there steps 3-5? What is the most logical and clear approach?

Comment: As of now I created the following function (but within main class, which is not very good): String formUrl(), String getFilmsBrowse(url); void parseFilmsBrowseAndDBUpdate(jsonString). All of them are started in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need an Adapter class for your ListView. Also you'll need a parser class(you can implement SAX or DOM if response is XML). Take a look at [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) to understand image downloading into ListView. 
Your parser class can return an array of custom objects and then you'll supply it to listview via your custom adapter class.

Comment: Thanks, @Mighter. This is already done. My question is about organizing the same - what should be in one function, what should in different, what to place in each class etc.